# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'panTo' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular-google-maps

I am trying to pan to some lat and lng, while panning the above error is getting displayed.
But it shows the above error.

component.ts

```
public map: any;
zoom; 
lat;
currentLoc: boolean; 
lng;
constructor() {

        this.zoom = 12;
        this.lat = 12.972442;
        this.lng = 77.580643;

}

 ngOnInit() {
   this.setCurrentPosition();
}

 private setCurrentPosition() {
        console.log('setting');
        this.currentLoc = true;
        if ('geolocation' in navigator) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
                this.lat = position.coords.latitude;
                this.lng = position.coords.longitude;
                this.zoom = 12;
            });
        }
    }


public mapReady(map) {
        this.map = map;
    }`

 drawOnMap() {
for (let i = 0; i < this.Locations.length; i++) {
                        // console.log(this.Locations[i].latitude, this.Locations[i].longitude);
                        const coordinate = new Coordinate(this.Locations[i].latitude, this.Locations[i].longitude);
                        // console.log( 'Coordinate is :' + coordinate);
                        this.coordinates.push(coordinate);
                        this.map.panTo({ lat: this.Locations[0].latitude, lng: this.Locations[0].longitude });
                    }
}
```

> this.Locations[] is having some lats and lng, it is not empty

Html

```
<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [zoom]="zoom" [styles]="styles" (mapReady)="mapReady($event)">
                <agm-marker *ngFor="let marker of coordinates; let i = index" [iconUrl]="station" [latitude]="marker.latitude" [longitude]="marker.longitude"
                    [markerClickable]="true" (markerClick)="markerClicked(marker.latitude,marker.longitude)">
                </agm-marker>
                <agm-marker *ngIf="currentLoc === true" [iconUrl]="Liveicon" [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng">
                </agm-marker>
<agm-map>
```

Please correct me where I am wrong. I am not able to get this.

Comment: can you log the value of map in your mapReady(map) function and check the value.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simple, the map is simply never instantiated.

In the html, the mapRead() method is listening for itself to fire in order to initiate the map which will never happen if you don't call it from from the outside.

The solution is easy. Just instantiate the map in the constructor or on ngOnInit, like so:

```js
...

ngOnInit() {
  this.map = map;
}

...
```

In this case the mapRead method is redundant. Unless you want to dynamically instantiate your map.

Comment: what is the value of map you are assigning?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the whole setCurrentPosition method is not needed, Fortunately, the angular google maps package does a lot of things for you so all you need to do to change the position (and focus)  of the map is to change this.lat and this.lng.